# Removeall function based on a condition not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I am written a program with Knockout using observableArray and I want to delete an element from that array based on a condition. But it is not working, my program is like this:

```
 var app = function (appname, appdesc,isactive) {
            this.appname = appname;
            this.appdesc = appdesc;
            this.active = isactive;
        }
        var mainVM = function () {
            var app1 = new app('sap', 'sap b1', false);
            var app2 = new app('Magento', 'Magento 1', false);
            //this.appList = ko.observableArray();
            this.appList = ko.observableArray([app1, app2]);
        }
        var appVM = new mainVM();
        ko.applyBindings(appVM)

$('#btnDel').click(function () {

            appVM.appList.removeAll([{ "active": false }]);
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a `removeAll` function by sending a parameter `{'active': false}`. In other words, you are asking Knockout to determine if any of the `app` instances inside `appList` is equal to the object `{'active': false}`. They are not equal!

This is app1:

```
{
   appname: 'sap',
   appdesc: 'sap b1',
   active: false
}
```

This is app2:

```
{
   appname: 'Magento',
   appdesc: 'Magento 1',
   active: false
}
```

And the parameter you're passing for comparison is this:

```
{
   active: false
}
```

They are very different.

---

Even if you create 2 instances with identical inputs they are not equal. Look here:

```js
var app = function (appname, appdesc,isactive) {
    this.appname = appname;
    this.appdesc = appdesc;
    this.active = isactive;
}

var app1 = new app('moo', 'coo', false);
var app2 = new app('moo', 'coo', false);

document.getElementById('secret').innerHTML = (app1 === app2);
```

```html
is app1 equal to app2?

<br><br>

<span id="secret"></span>
```

---

So the original option which I had suggested, `remove`, is the right function for you, when you are dealing with objects.

```js
var app = function (appname, appdesc,isactive) {
            this.appname = appname;
            this.appdesc = appdesc;
            this.active = isactive;
        }
        var mainVM = function () {
            var app1 = new app('sap', 'sap b1', true);
            var app2 = new app('Magento', 'Magento 1', false);
            //this.appList = ko.observableArray();
            this.appList = ko.observableArray([app1, app2]);
        }
        var appVM = new mainVM();
        ko.applyBindings(appVM)

        $('#btnDel').click(function () {

            appVM.appList.remove(function(item){
              return !item.active;
            });
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- ko foreach: appList -->
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></span>
<br>
<!-- /ko -->

<br><br>
<button id="btnDel">Delete</button>
```

---

`removeAll` with parameters is only useful in this kind of scenario, where it is a primitive datatype:

```js
var mainVM = function () {
            
            this.appList = ko.observableArray([false, true]);
        }
        var appVM = new mainVM();
        ko.applyBindings(appVM)

        $('#btnDel').click(function () {

            appVM.appList.removeAll([false]);
        })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko foreach: appList -->
<span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></span>
<br>
<!-- /ko -->

<br><br>
<button id="btnDel">Delete</button>
```

Comment: But in the documentation it is written that we can pass parameter in removeall() method. removeAll( ['Chad', 132, undefined] ) — Removes all values that equal 'Chad', 123, or undefined and returns them as an array.

Comment: Aah you're right my bad. I never noticed that before. I've updated my answer.